# Windows phone ad mediation ads not showing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, ads

Yesterday, in my windows phone 8 application i've replaced admob ads with ad mediator control provided by Microsoft.
I was following this tutorial:

https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Inside-Windows-Platform/Inside-Windows-Platform--Inside-the-Windows-Ad-Mediator-Service-and-Control-Maximize-your-Ad-Revenue

Yesterday while i was testing the app on emulator and on my test device, the ads were showing (on emulator test ads, on device real ads).

After i submitted the update for my app on windows phone store, only the ad control is showing with black background and then it totally disappears, no ads are showing, nothing.

I have checked ad units ids and all required capabilities and also tried to change refresh rate and the percentage of distribution of ads on my windows phone dashboard, but it's not working.

Does anyone have the same problem with ad mediation or some solution how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

While uploading the app update or a new app to the store, you have to **fill the required details again like Ad Unit Id**, etc... Make sure you fill them every time you upload an app update or a new App. I had the same issue but the above solved my problem. Hope it helps you.

Comment: required details again like Ad Unit Id in windows developer account ?